# How to customize PHPStorm comments?

Tags: php, settings, phpstorm

This is an auto created comment block in PHPStorm

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by 
 * User: 
 * Date: 
 * Time: 
 */
```

I want to customize the block
(Eg: instead of Created by use Author etc)
I tried in settings.
Could not figure out.

Comment: Is this a _PHP_ issue, or _PHPStorm_ issue?

Comment: @Idris PHPStorm issue

Comment: I don't know why people gave this question a negative 2. I didn't know how to do this and this is the only question with perfect answer on how to change that. Thanks for posting the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to `Settings` -> `IDE Settings` -> `File and Code Templates`.

Then on `Includes` tab select `PHP File Header` item.

Also relevant: `Templates` tab, `PHP File` item.

Answer (score 1):

In latest versions the settings is under

`Settings` -> `Editor` -> `File and Code Templates` -> `Includes` -> `PHP File Header`